# Write multiple rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

My current codeigniter .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

And there are 2 .htaccess placed. 
One at the root and another in application folder.

I want to write following rewrite rules at a time:

**1.**  Remove index.php

**2.** Force redirect www.example.com  to http**s**://example.com

**3.** Force redirect http.example.com  to http**s**://example.com

**4.** Force redirect www.example.com/cart  to http**s**://example.com/cart

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And in config.php (codeignter):

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I hope that helped :)